# Velocity adding values with in concatenation statement

Tags: string, velocity

Apologies if this has been asked before but i could not find a straightforward answer.

I have the following code, the application is a third party so the incoming $supernet is provided as a string. So what i am wanting to do it take a IP address and then manipulate it to create a list of subnets based on a template.

```
#set ($Supernet = "10.10.10.10") 
#set ($octs = $Supernet.split("\."))

#set ($netmgmt[2] = "$octs[0].$octs[1].$octs[2].$octs[2]+1")

$netmgmt
```

But this as I expect gives the result "10.10.10.10+1"

I figured out I can do this in a longhand way

1. convert the $oct[2] to an integer and store in a variable
2. create a temporary variable and store the result of the converted $oct[2] + 1
3. Then use this to create the string

like

```
$Integer = $convert.toInteger($oct[2])
#set ($newoct = $Integer + 1) 
#set ($netmgmt[2] = "$octs[0].$octs[1].$octs[2].$newoct")
```

but i have a lot of these to create and this will get long winded and confusing.

So i am trying to work out if I can write #set ($octs = $Supernet.split(".")) to store as integers. To be honest just trying to directly convert each array value to int does not seem to work as based on what i have found on line. I expected the below would result in "$oct1 = 10" but it does not?

```
#set ($Supernet = "10.10.10.10") 
#set ($octs = $Supernet.split("\."))
#set ($oct1 = $convert.toInteger($oct[0])
```

New to Velocity any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check which version of Velocity-Tools you are using, and which tools are available in the provided context.

Since Velocity-Tools 3.1, for instance, `$convert.toInteger()` has been deprecated in favor of `$math.toInteger()`. You can check if those tools are present in the context just by displaying `$convert` and `$math`.

The following code works for me with Velocity 1.7 + Tools 2.0, as long as with Velocity 2.X + Tools 3.x:

```
#set ($Supernet = "10.10.10.10")
#set ($octs = $Supernet.split('\.'))
#set ($last = $math.toInteger($octs[2]) - 1)
#set ($ip = "${octs[0]}.${octs[1]}.${octs[2]}.$last")
$ip
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, you comment sent me down the right path :) the command i needed is #set ($last = $integer.parseInt($octs[2]) - 1).